# View log-levels for entries added by “logger” command

Tags: macos, logs, console

I log with `/usr/bin/logger`, which provides a switch `-p` to set the priority. Example:

```sh
logger -p user.warning "My program crashed."
```

I can see this message via the Console, but I don’t see its logging priority “warning” mentioned anywhere. I tried `user.debug` and `user.info` as well, which doesn’t make any difference. `log show` doesn’t explicitly show log level either; the only way I can somewhat tell a debug-level log is that whether the log entry disappears when I skip the `--debug` command. So this information is definitely stored somewhere; is there any way I can see it directly?

Note: this question is only about log entries created by the `logger` command, not by any GUI application.

Comment: Note: I think `logger` is part of the new [Unified Logging System](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging).

Comment: You can get some additional information by specifying different output styles such as `json`, but I don't see the log level (or tags) even with this more verbose output.